# Group-documenting a group of enum mebers

Tags: doxygen

Is it possible to document a group of enum values, similar to this (this example doesn't work):

```
enum MyEnum
{
  MYENUM_FIRST,
//@{
//@name These two members' description
  MYENUM_SECOND,
  MYENUM_THIRD,
//@}

  MYENUM_FOURTH, ///third member documentation
  MYENUM_FIFTH
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two immediate things which stand out:

- You are not documenting `MYENUM_SECOND` or `MYENUM_THIRD` since you have not wrapped them with valid doxygen comments: your should write `///@{` instead of `//@{`.
- Your documentation of `MYENUM_FOURTH` should be

  ```
  ///< third member documentation
  ```

  otherwise you are documenting `MYENUM_FIFTH` instead of `MYENUM_FOURTH`.

I could get documentation for both `MYENUM_SECOND` and `MYENUM_THIRD` by using the following code

```
enum MyEnum
{
  MYENUM_FIRST,
  ///@{
  /// These two members' description
  MYENUM_SECOND,
  MYENUM_THIRD,
  ///@}

  MYENUM_FOURTH, ///< third member documentation
  MYENUM_FIFTH
};
```

and by setting `DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC = YES` in the configuration file. Note that I have removed the `\name` command from your example.

Comment: I'm sorry for the stupid mistakes, I put the example a bit in a hurry. My original idea was to have a headline above the group, in bold, not to have the same documentation for both members, Hence the  '@name' tag. It seems not possible to use '@name' tag in this case. But having the same doc is also a good idea. It seems doxygen allows both //@{ and ///@{, as an example from the doxygen doc shows - but maybe they mean different things? I wanted to post the example, but the char limit doesn't allow me.

Comment: You can always edit your question to add more code examples. Instead of a "headline", why don't you document the `enum` itself?

Comment: @WernerHenze This question has an accepted answer. If you've got a different question, please create a new question.